# Unable to Install Plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to install plotly library in my shiny server(Ubuntu 14.04). I am using `devtools` to install `plotly`.

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
```

I am observing the following:

```
Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/plotly@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ropensci/plotly/zipball/master
Installing plotly
Skipping 3 unavailable packages: ggplot2, plyr, tidyr
Installing 1 package: viridis
Installing package into â/home/shiny/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0â
(as âlibâ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/viridis_0.3.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1764427 bytes (1.7 Mb)

opened URL

downloaded 1.7 Mb

* installing *source* package âviridisâ ...
** package âviridisâ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  namespace âggplot2â 0.9.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package âviridisâ
* removing â/home/shiny/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/viridisâ

The downloaded source packages are in
        â/tmp/RtmpNULrLF/downloaded_packagesâ
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpNULrLF/devtools59af4cc18d9c/ropensci-plotly-d2e5adf'  \
  --library='/home/shiny/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0' --install-tests


ERROR: dependencies âviridisâ, âtidyrâ are not available for package âplotlyâ
* removing â/home/shiny/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/plotlyâ
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
In utils::install.packages(pkgs, repos = repos, type = type, dependencies = dependencies,  :
  installation of package âviridisâ had non-zero exit status
```

I am also trying `install.packages("plotly")` and I am hitting the error.

```
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("plotly") :
  installation of package âviridisâ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("plotly") :
  installation of package âplotlyâ had non-zero exit status
```

Can someone help with the error?

Comment: You may want to include some of the results of `sessionInfo`.

Comment: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_IN
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_IN     LC_MONETARY=en_IN    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_IN       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your ggplot2 package. Your problem is an error in a dependency package, viridis. The error message says `namespace ggplot2 0.9.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required`. The [namespace file](https://github.com/sjmgarnier/viridis/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) for viridis says it wants a more recent version of ggplot.

Comment: I tried to install ggplot from CRAN but ended up in error package âggplot2â is not available (for R version 3.0.2), so i used sudo apt-get install r-cran-ggplot2. Is this the cause for older version of ggplot2. Kindly let me know the way to update ggplot2 to new version

Comment: Looks like you'll need to update your version of R. Looking at [the docs](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/DESCRIPTION), for the most recent version of ggplot2 `Depends R (>= 3.1)`, so you're a bit out of date. If you're on Ubuntu 14.04 you should be able to do a `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` to fix the problem.

Comment: i tried all the possibilities, i also uninstalled and installed R again. But i am again getting R 3.0.2. Is there anyway to go to higher version.

Comment: r-base is already the newest version.
i am getting this output

Comment: That's because it's the newest version in the Ubuntu repository. You'll have to manually set you CRAN mirror to get the latest version from CRAN. Check out [this link](https://www.datascienceriot.com/33/kris/)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. That help me to fix it :)

Comment: I'd rather refer to the official [CRAN site](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#installation) for the installation than posting a link to a blog.